HTTPSConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded with URL Caused by SSLError
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from urllib3 import disable_warnings

# Deaktiviere Warnungen für unsicheres SSL
disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

url = 'https://172.16.60.2/'

# Zertifikatsprüfung deaktivieren
try:
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Erfolgreiche Antwort:", response.text)
    else:
        print(f"Anfrage fehlgeschlagen. Statuscode: {response.status_code}, Antwort: {response.text}")
except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
    print(f"SSL-Fehler: {e}")


**
Error message
SSL-Fehler: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.16.60.2', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1000)')))**
enter image description here
i tried this too:
HTTPSConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded with URL (Caused by SSLError)
still the same problem
please help me.
Thanks!
